# C#: is there a way to determine if a range of elements is empty?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm wondering if theres a method to determine whether a certain range of array elements is empty or not. for example, if the array was initialized with 10 elements having the values "", then if data was later assigned to elements 5, 7, 9; could i test if elements 0-3 were empty, or rather contained an empty string ""?

Comment: Couldn't you simply start the array with 10 nulls instead of 10 empty strings? ( "" != null )

Comment: my first crack at this was doing something like if(Array.IndexOf(array, "") < 4) which is just seeing if there was a blank entry in the first four elements. Seems kind of clunky though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array.Skip(startIndex).Take(count).All(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

So, if you are trying to check elements 0-3:

```
array.Skip(0).Take(4).All(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

For clarity, I left `Skip` in there.

**Edit:** made it `Take(4)` instead of 3 as per Jonathan's comment in the other answer (and now Guffa's comment in mine. ;)  ).

**Edit 2:** According to comments below, the OP wanted to see if *any* of the elements matched:

```
array.Skip(0).Take(4).Any(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

So changed `All` to `Any`.

Comment: That only checks elements 0-2.

Comment: ok i think this makes sense. But doesn't this only check if the entire range is blank? I guess I should have been more specific. Basically what I'm trying to do is determine if any of the elements in that range contain a blank

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, modified answer, but use the `Any` operator instead of `All`.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool is0to3empty = myArrayOfString.Skip(0).Take(4).All(i => string.IsNullOrEmpty(i));
```

Comment: @Jonathan yes but I don't think the exact number is really the question here.

Comment: I worry that someone will see Take(3) and think it means "Take all the elements indexed up through 3".

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward and efficient would be to simply loop through that part of the array:

```
bool empty = true;..
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(theArray[i])) {
    empty = false;
    break;
  }
}
if (empty) {
  // items 0..3 are empty
}
```

Another alternative would be to use extension methods to do the looping:

```
bool empty = theArray.Take(4).All(String.IsNullOrEmpty);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create this extension class and you can call it from any string array:

```
    public static class IsEmptyInRangeExtension
    {
        public static bool IsEmptyInRange(this IEnumerable<string> strings, int startIndex, int endIndex)
        {
            return strings.Skip(startIndex).TakeWhile((x, index) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && index <= endIndex).Count() > 0;
        }

    }
```